# Why is the method not acting "properly?"

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I get the numbers scanned in correctly, but the methods aren't working right. First one doesn't do anything and the second one goes into an infinite loop.

Method called is not performing correctly. I am not sure what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testSequence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
  int enterNumber = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("1 for Iteration, 2 for Recursion: ");
  int type = scan.nextInt();

  if (type == 1){
      computeIteration(enterNumber);
  } else if (type == 2){
      computeRecursion(enterNumber);
  }
}


public static int computeIteration(int enterNumber) {
    int answer;
    int multiplier = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int addend = 0;
    if (enterNumber == 0) {
        count++;
        return enterNumber;
    } else if (enterNumber == 1) {
        count++;
        return enterNumber;
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i <= enterNumber; i++) {//need to adjust "i" for counter correction

            enterNumber = (multiplier * 2) + addend;
            addend = multiplier;
            multiplier = enterNumber;
            count += 1;
        }//end for loop
        answer = enterNumber;
    }//end else
    return answer;
}//end computeIteration

public static int computeRecursion(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        count++;
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        count++;
        return 1;
    } else {
        count++;
        return computeRecursion(2 * (n - 1)) + computeRecursion(n - 2);
    }

}//end computerRecursion()

}//end Sequence()
```

Comment: I see that you're calling `computeIteration`, but then you don't do anything with the result.  Might that be part of the problem?

Comment: You are increasing ìnt count` on several places in both methods, but you do not use it.

Comment: Murillio4 I know that, thank you. I am more concerned with why the method is not working right. @ajb it is supposed return the answer but the answer doesn't display at all.

Comment: Where is the statement that displays the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never printing the answer.

```
if (type == 1){
      computeIteration(enterNumber);
  } else if (type == 2){
      computeRecursion(enterNumber);
  }
```

Note how you're calling the functions, but you never do anything with the result.

You probably meant:

```
if (type == 1){
    System.out.println(computeIteration(enterNumber));
  } else if (type == 2){
    System.out.println(computeRecursion(enterNumber));
  }
```

Or, if you wanted to get fancy:

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> f =
    type == 1 ? 
        computeIteration
        : computeRecursion;

System.out.println( f.apply(enterNumber) ) ;
```

Just an addition since you asked.  I'm using the ternary operator because I need to choose between 2 things. In a case like this, it's neater than a full `if` statement.

The `UnaryOperator` is a functional interface. Basically, using them, you can save a function inside a variable. This is useful where in cases like this, you want to choose between 2 functions whose signatures are the same (both of your functions take an int, and give back an int), and use the result.

I save one of your functions into `f`, then call it by writing `f.apply(9)` (`apply` "applies" the arguments to the function; calling it).

Note you shouldn't use functional interfaces just for kicks, as they can make code less clear. When used properly though, they can make code **much** simpler; especially when paired with anonymous functions.

Comment: That is what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: what is the bottom one actually doing? That looks MUCH more advanced than I have ever seen (which isn't much) It looks similar to what I know as a tertiary operator from "C" Am I even close?

Comment: @platypus87 Ya, the ternary operator is just a ternary operator. Works the same. I'll write a quick description of what the rest does in a bit.

Comment: haha, "ternary" not "tertiary" ... what a dum dum, lol. I appreciate the <upcoming> description.

Comment: Now that I made the edits, though, I am getting a return, but it seems to be the location, not the actual number. it is printing -1128151334. Here is what I changed it to:
    `if (type == 1){

 System.out.println(computeIteration(enterNumber));

  } else if (type == 2){

      System.out.println(computeRecursion(enterNumber));

  }`

Comment: @platypus87 Note you never use `count` in  your recursive function. I'm struggling to see its purpose.

Comment: Also, the first 2 if branches could be reduced to `if (n == 1 || n == 2) { return n; }`.

Comment: The purpose if for my actual project that I am doing for class. This program was meant to test the functionality of this particular portion of the code. The project involves a GUI and I struggle making the GUI work right. I can't even get THIS right...The count is to eventually compare the number of steps taken with the incursion method as opposed to the recursion method.

Comment: @platypus87 You'll need to learn to debug code. It's absolutely crucial to coding. Put `System.out.println`s all over the place if you need to to see what's going on inside your program. Or, better yet, learn to use a debugger.  Your code will go wrong sometimes. You need to learn how to understand what's going on inside your code as it runs.

Comment: @platypus87 Put a `println` inside of your recursive function, and print the value of `n`. See what happens.

Comment: I will try that, but I am now having issues with the result of printing the result from computeIteration(). It seems to be printing the location of where it is being stored rather than the result itself. I prefer to work on one problem at a time...that is why it takes me SO damn long to do this stuff

Comment: @platypus87 what do you mean "location"? Try printing out the values of some variables in the iterative function too and see if there are any surprises.

Comment: When I input 0 or 1 they are returned as they are supposed to be. However, when I type in ANY other number, -112815334 gets returned.

Comment: What I am pretty sure happened is that I use "enterNumber" in my loop, but keep resetting it in the loop so I think the negative number is where the computer couldn't fit anymore numbers in the "int" spot. all I need to do is change the variable that I am using in the loop. Thanks to your println debugging tip, I figured that out.

Comment: @platypus87 Np. If you do plan to start coding though, I highly recommend learning to use a debugger. They basically let you pause your program wherever you want, and let you see the values of everything. "Print debugging" is useful for quick things, but if you find yourself wanting to know the values of several variables at once, use a debugger for the sake of your own sanity.

Comment: Thanks I will do that. I use NetBeans and it has a debugging tool I just haven't reached that level yet.